# Is $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ locally integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Can we say since its anti-derivative is like $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt x$, even if we study the measurable bounded set near zero, the anti-derivative will not go to infinity, and hence the original function is locally integrable？

Comment: Yes.  Your reasoning is correct.